# Bluetooth weak signal

Tags: bluetooth, nokia-lumia-1520

After the recent repair I've encountered some sort of a problem with my Lumia 1520. Problem is, that Bluetooth/WiFi signal has become much weaker since that repair. Listening to music using Bluetooth headset is available only at distance of 0.5 meters. Putting the phone into the pocket means scrambled signal. Signal starts breaking when I put my fingers on the top right corner of the phone. Three different service centers said, that the antenna itself is intact. Trying to downgrade the phone to WP 8.1 didn't help. 
What can cause the low signal?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried any other bluetooth headsets? Are you sure it is not a problem with headset?

Answer (score 1):

Resetting your Device is of utmost importance. If its not downgraded(Due to firmware upgrade) get it Formatted by yourself or from company customer care center. Even if They are able to format your Device and reinstall everything but still issue persists then in that case I would highly recommend to Get your hardware fixed by Customer care.